# Getting error in Android Studio 2.1 with java 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, java-8

Currently I am using `java 8` with latest `android studio 2.1`

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "24rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
.......
}
```

I am getting the below compile time error that I have no clue

> Error:com.android.jack.frontend.FrontendCompilationException: Failed
>   to compile    at com.android.jack.Jack.buildSession(Jack.java:892)    at
>   com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:472)  at
>   com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:102)
>     ... 8 more Warning:Exception while processing task
>   java.io.IOException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException:
>   Failed to compile :oTT:compileDebugJavaWithJack FAILED Error:Execution
>   failed for task ':oTT:compileDebugJavaWithJack'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException: Failed to compile Information:BUILD FAILED

Please feel to ask if you need some details.

Comment: Remove compileOptions in build.gradle file ...then try..

Comment: @SarithaG Tried but giving the same error :)

Comment: change your buildToolsVersion "24rc3" line to  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"..

Comment: @SarithaG .It now showing the below error  Error:Execution failed for task ':name:jillDebugPackagedLibraries'.
> Jack requires Build Tools 24.0.0 or later

Comment: @Soham Any luck with this? I am getting the same error...

Comment: @JoelMin .I have to downgrade java version as I was not able to find any suitable solution for the same.

Comment: Thanks Soham, I'll downgrade to 1.7 and see if it works for me.

Comment: @JoelMin Does Java 1.7 work for you?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had this error too, and what I found was that the error itself was masking another compilation issue.  Look at your Console Messages carefully and see if there is something else not compiling.  Once I solved the underlying issue with my own code, this error magically disappeared.   Hope this helps.

Comment: I checked all the changed files and found a compilation error in one of my file.

Comment: well i have problems with resources letters _ñ_

Comment: yes in this case android studio didn't highlight me for some java code and XML errors. so I manually open all source file one by one and then studio highlighted me file errors, now RESOLVED

Answer (score 2):

Try to use next values:

```
compileSdkVersion = "android-N"
buildToolsVersion = "24.0.0 rc3"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I have already tried that and didn't able to solve though.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0-rc3'
```

note the dash before rc3. This is according to http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html under the section "Update an existing project"

I am using 23 just for the lambda.

the following link shows the Supported Java 8 Language Features and APIs https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

Comment: java 8 streams work or don't work in (also available on API level 23 and lower)?

Comment: @Denis,  not sure, I didn't try streams. I am already using https://bitbucket.org/mart_bogdan/collectionsquery/src, so it'll be a chore to change all my codes.

Comment: Java 8 Language Features

https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#configuration

java.util.stream - but i don't know, can i use them with min version about 15-18api

Comment: wow, "CollectionsQuery" - it's library like c# linq (i like c# linq). Good library?

Answer (score 2):

I think we are all looking mostly at the same answer. To be precise I'd say "make sure the `buildToolsVersion = "[version]"` is the **same** as the `[version]` in the error".
For some this will be `24.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Some java 8 features only support Android N. read android docs
http://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html#configuration

When I use Default Methods on sdk23, I got this error too. so update your sdk version to Android N.

Comment: Yes I already read that link and tried with that but didn't resolved.